# How to retrieve publish output using volume when run Docker file

Tags: .net, docker, dockerfile, gitlab-ci

I am unable to retrieve /app/publish content from container.
Docker file locks like

```
...
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["HellodAPI/HelloAPI.csproj", "HelloAPI/"]
RUN dotnet restore "HellodAPI/HellodAPI.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/HelloAPI"
RUN dotnet build "HelloAPI.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "HelloAPI.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "HelloAPI.dll"]
```

I am using Gitlab Ci and the code looks like this:

```
Build job:
  stage: build
  image:
    name:  amazon/aws-cli
    entrypoint: [""]
  variables:
    MOUNT_POINT: /builds/$CI_PROJECT_PATH/app/build
  before_script:
    - amazon-linux-extras install docker
    - aws --version
    - docker --version
    - yum install -y tar
  services:
    - docker:dind
  script:
     - mkdir -p ${MOUNT_POINT}
     - docker build --target publish -f HelloAPI/Dockerfile -t xxx/helloapi:$CI_PIPELINE_IID .
     - docker run --rm -v ${MOUNT_POINT}:/src/app xxx/helloapi:$CI_PIPELINE_IID
     - tar -czvf publish.tar.gz ${MOUNT_POINT}/*
     - cp publish.tar.gz ${CI_PROJECT_DIR}
  artifacts:
    when: on_success
    paths:
      - ./publish.tar.gz
```

I can publish and run but tar command return this error:

```
tar: /builds/xxxx/xxxx/app/publish/*: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set your mount point in the container to `/src/app` but the app directory is actually located at the root because of `WORKDIR /app`. So I think this would work:

```
docker run --rm -v ${MOUNT_POINT}:/app xxx/helloapi:$CI_PIPELINE_IID
```

Comment: Thanks so much @ Matt Thalman. Works very well.

Comment: Please mark this as an answer if it solved your issue.